# Getting Handbrake encoder to work

Tags: c#, exception, video-encoding, handbrake

I am unable to get [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) to work for me in C#. It keeps throwing the error "Value cannot be null." . As you can see in the screenshot below, I've tried a couple of things based on what I know. I would appreciate any of your guidance to help me get this work.

[image: Handbrake Encoder error]

What I've tried so far (points are not relevant to the error displayed..Just FYI) :

1. Installed handbrake on my pc
2. Added a reference to HandBrakeInterop.dll
3. Copied all the other required dlls to my debug folder and even tried adding them as references
4. Tried changing debug versions from x86/x64

Where am I not on the right track?

Here's my code :

```
      HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance objHb = new HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance();
    HandBrake.Interop.Model.EncodeJob objJob = new HandBrake.Interop.Model.EncodeJob();
    objJob.SourceType = HandBrake.Interop.Model.SourceType.File;
    EncodingProfile objProfile = new EncodingProfile();
    objProfile.OutputFormat = Container.Mp4;
    objProfile.VideoEncodeRateType = VideoEncodeRateType.ConstantQuality;
    objProfile.IPod5GSupport = true;
    objProfile.PreferredExtension = OutputExtension.Mp4;
   // objJob.EncodingProfile = objProfile;
    objJob.SourcePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "1.flv";
    objJob.OutputPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "1.mp4";
    //objHb.Titles.Add(new HandBrake.Interop.SourceData.Title());

    XmlSerializer objSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EncodingProfile));


   MemoryStream mem=new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "normal.xml"));
 var objPresetFromFile =  objSerializer.Deserialize(mem) as EncodingProfile;
 objJob.EncodingProfile = objPresetFromFile;
    objJob.UseDefaultChapterNames = true;
   // objJob.Title = 1;



    //HandBrake.Interop.Model.Encoders
    objHb.EncodeProgress += objHb_EncodeProgress;
    objHb.EncodeCompleted += objHb_EncodeCompleted;
    HandBrake.ApplicationServices.Parsing.Title title = new HandBrake.ApplicationServices.Parsing.Title();// new HandBrake.Interop.SourceData.Title();
    objHb.Initialize(5);
    //objHb.Titles = new System.Collections.Generic.List<HandBrake.Interop.SourceData.Title>();
    objHb.StartScan(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "1.flv", 0);
    objJob.SourceType = HandBrake.Interop.Model.SourceType.File;
    objJob.RangeType = HandBrake.Interop.Model.VideoRangeType.Frames;

    objHb.StartEncode(objJob);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

EDIT : As requested,here's more info from the exception copied to clipboard

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
  Source=System.Core
  ParamName=source
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.GetTitle(Int32 titleNumber) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 1604
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.GetTitleIndex(Int32 titleNumber) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 1614
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.StartEncode(EncodeJob job, Boolean preview, Int32 previewNumber, Int32 previewSeconds, Double overallSelectedLengthSeconds) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 411
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.StartEncode(EncodeJob jobToStart) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 395
       at HandBrakeTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HandBrakeTest\HandBrakeTest\Program.cs:line 53
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Edit :

1. Moved handbrakeinstance and encodingjob's instance outside main and made them static
2. Calling StartEncode in scan completed event

Now, the exception is Nullreferenceexception with this in the details :

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=HandBrakeInterop
  StackTrace:
       at HandBrake.Interop.InteropUtilities.ReadStructure[T](IntPtr structPtr) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\InteropUtilities.cs:line 31
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.StartEncode(EncodeJob job, Boolean preview, Int32 previewNumber, Int32 previewSeconds, Double overallSelectedLengthSeconds) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 412
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.StartEncode(EncodeJob jobToStart) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 395
       at HandBrakeTest.Program.objHb_ScanCompleted(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HandBrakeTest\HandBrakeTest\Program.cs:line 65
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.PollScanProgress() in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 811
       at HandBrake.Interop.HandBrakeInstance.<StartScan>b__2(Object o, ElapsedEventArgs e) in c:\HandBrake\Hudson\workspace\Release_WindowsGui64\0.9.9\win\CS\HandBrake.Interop\HandBrakeInterop\HandBrakeInstance.cs:line 752
       at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
  InnerException:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a link on that popup: "Copy exception details to clipboard". Paste that information into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah HandBrakeInterop isn't the easiest API to just write some code for; it's more geared toward full encoder GUIs right now; it doesn't fall back on defaults very well. You had a really good idea in just taking the EncodingProfile from the XML.

Here's a working, minimal project that interacts with HandBrakeInterop:
http://engy.us/misc/HandBrakeInteropExample.zip

Some relevant bits:

```
instance = new HandBrakeInstance();
instance.Initialize(verbosity: 1);
instance.ScanCompleted += instance_ScanCompleted;
instance.StartScan(SourceFile, previewCount: 10);
```

- 1 is the default verbosity. The "5" you were passing in isn't valid.
- You'll probably want to pass in a real value for the previewCount on StartScan: it uses these static previews to do things like automatic cropping detection and combing detection.

```
var job = new EncodeJob
    {
        EncodingProfile = profile,
        RangeType = VideoRangeType.All,
        Title = 1,
        SourcePath = SourceFile,
        OutputPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Output.mp4",
        ChosenAudioTracks = new List { 1 },
        Subtitles = new Subtitles
            {
                SourceSubtitles = new List(),
                SrtSubtitles = new List()
            }
    };
```

- You need to pass in which title to encode (1-based index). For files this is rarely relevant; the feature is designed for DVD/Blu-ray scans.
- You have to pass in both a `RangeType` and the specifics for the range: for example if you pick a `RangeType` of `Frames` then you need to specify `FramesStart` and `FramesEnd`. `RangeType.All` is easiest since you don't need to specify anything extra.
- You need to specify a list of the chosen audio tracks indices (1-based). Not normally useful for files, but for DVD/Blu-ray discs that have multiple languages.
- Right now you have to give it something under Subtitles or it will crash out. This is actually a bug; there were a few cases I wasn't guarding correctly. I'll fix this up in the future.

Check out [VidCoder](https://vidcoder.codeplex.com/) if you want to see a full reference implementation of the API. HandBrake has started to use it some but it hasn't gotten around to all the features like static previews and pause/resume.

**Update**: The code required now looks completely different and targets HandBrake.ApplicationServices.dll. New minimal project: http://engy.us/misc/HBInteropExampleV3.zip

A notable difference is that the encode job is now specified in JSON. This is the exact same JSON blob that is spit out in the encode log in HandBrake/VidCoder, so you can steal it from there and tweak it.

Comment: WOW,What more can I ask for! Thank you bro. I tried Vidcoder and looked into it's source code too. Infact, for usability, I prefer Vidcoder over handbrake. The implementation of the piping and queue system are way too good. I wish VidCoder had an API.Thank you for all your great work. i've recommended VidCoder on the Handbrake forum too.

Comment: @RandomEngy - excellent post.  I tried the example you linked but I get this error: Unable to load DLL 'hb.dll': The specified module could not be found.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @steveo40 hb.dll is there in the zip file. Maybe copy it to your output directory?

Comment: @RandomEngy, Your sample helped a lot, Thank you. would you remember the corresponding Handbreak release version?
 I do not find "HandBrakeInterop, Version=1.41.0.0" in the Handbreak package, I see either "'HandBrakeInterop, Version=1.40.0.0" or 'HandBrakeInterop, Version=1.51.0.0"...

Comment: @RandomEngy, the reason I need this, I want to use the latest version without making any code changes...somehow 'HandBrakeInterop, Version=1.40.0.0" and 'HandBrakeInterop, Version=1.51.0.0" is not working. The only thing works is what ever you have in the sample.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar Edited answer with new minimal project.

Comment: @RandomEngy, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RandomEngy, In terms of converting .avi and .wmv - what difference would the new version make? I am trying to build a console application that would process the .avi/.wmv.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar There are many changes. You can read in detail here: https://handbrake.fr/news.php

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look at the source code [here](https://trac.handbrake.fr/browser/trunk/win/CS/HandBrake.Interop/HandBrakeInterop/HandBrakeInstance.cs). It appears that `StartScan` is actually an asynchronous call and you must wait for the `ScanCompleted` event to be raised before calling `StartEncode`.

What seems to be happening is that the `Titles` collection is null. This is populated in a private method `PollScanProgress` which seems to fire on a timer that checks for the progress of a scan. The timer is setup in `StartScan`.

Comment: Thank you Mike..it seems like this took me one more step further. But, I'm still getting another exception..

Comment: @Josh I can't tell what exactly is going wrong now, but perhaps the events `HandBrakeUtils.MessageLogged` and `HandBrakeUtils.ErrorLogged`  may provide additional information.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts too Mike. I really appreciate it.